# XCode 4 Interface Builder: How to access a drawn object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4, interface-builder

I'm very new to iPhone development.

I drew a View using the Interface Builder in XCode 4. Currently the only thing inside is a Label (taken from the Object Library in the Interface Builder (So this is a UILabel, right?) ). I've set the tag of it to `6543` as recognizable test-value.

Now, I'm trying to write a method which prints out the tag. My problem is that I can't access the Label that I drew in the Interface Builder.

I know I can get the `tag` from an `id`, doing this:

```
int t = [myId tag];
```

So, I think the question is: **How to get an `id` of the Label I drew?**

And when that works, **how to edit the text of the Label**?

I think that when I know how to do these two things, I will be able to find out myself everything else that I want to do in my application.

I'm searching for about three hours, but I think I don't know the right terms to find any relevant info.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an outlet in your viewcontroller class and link this to the label. This is a fundamental principle of using interface builder. Xcode 4 can do this automatically for you by using the "assistant" editor ( the little chap with the bow tie) and control-dragging from the label to your class's .h file.

Comment: Aha, thanks it works. But it seems like the tag is not set before the view is actually visible.

Comment: Nothing from the xib file will be accessible until `viewDidLoad` has been called.

Comment: So and `viewDidLoad` will be called when I use `presentModalViewController`?

Comment: Yes. It is always called before the view is shown for the first time.

Comment: If you haven't already, Stanford University offers a free video course in iTunes University called iPhone Application Programming.  It walks you through step by step.  http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/